# How can the source and Destination register be same?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

Consider the basic processor organization to be as described in the image:

[image: Processor Organization]

For the micro-operation AR<-M[AR] (It reads the memory cell whose address is present in AR register and loads that memory word in AR register), I am not able to understand that how can we use AR register as a source as in it enables a particular memory cell and as destination as in the word gets fetched from memory and loaded to in AR at the same time. Here AR is the address register.

Comment: Im not specialist in processor architecture, but maybe [this](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/dataHazClass.html) article i what are you searching for?

Comment: For reading these diagrams we should assume that the AR (or any) register is read out at the beginning of a clock cycle, and is only updated at the end, just when the current cycle transitions into the next cycle.  A register's new/updated value therefore affects logic in the next clock cycle, not the current one. 
 Hardware designers have to concern themselves with a few more details than that, but generally for us software engineers these simplifying assumptions hold when reading such diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

Current digital computers are operating with electricity current, which "travels" at roughly 1/6 of light of speed, which may seem a lot, but it's still not "instant".

I.e. if you have logic gate AND, which takes two input lines, and has one output line, if you set up the input lines to 0 and 1, then output line is not instantly turned into 0, it takes few quantums of time before the output stabilizes to the resulting value.

To make the CPU (and whole computer) work in deterministic digital way, while being built from similar logical gates/circuits, the basic idea is set all input lines to desired states (the electricity current will immediately start to propagate through the circuitry toward outputs, setting them sooner or later to desired output level), stabilize them and after certain specific time (which is known to be enough to stabilize all output lines) to process the output signals. These time-steps are handled by the clock crystal, which signals to the circuitry the points in time when input/output signals are stable, splitting the continuous time into discrete steps. A CPU at 1kHz operates at 1000 discrete steps per second (single step may or may not cover whole operation, many early CPUs did need multiple steps to finish single machine code instruction, but everything was layouted and orchestrated in a way to work within these discrete time steps).

Let's call those steps "ticks" for simplicity, and let's assume your CPU being very simple and basic one (I can't access the image in your question right now, so I may be missing some important detail)

So what the `AR<-M[AR]` does is (a bit further complicated by the fact of memory chip being involved):

1. set up memory address lines to current AR value in the first tick and signals to memory chip that READ will be done -> waits for end of tick to stabilize these
2. in the second "tick" (or usually it takes them lot more, so the CPU idles as long as needed) the memory chip reads particular memory cell according to the address lines, and sets up data lines, and signals the value being ready back to the CPU
3. in the third tick the CPU will copy memory data lines content back to `AR` register, setting it up to new value, and instruction is done, next one can be processed.

So as you can see, it's not at the "same time", it's actually multiple "ticks" apart, the new value is set into AR at the moment when the old value doesn't matter any more for this instruction.

(modern CPUs like x86 have lot more complex architecture and logic to make this process parallel as much as possible, to the extent where such CPU can not only execute stream of instructions with average time 1 tick per instruction, but even execute multiple instructions in single tick, as long as they are using separate parts of the CPU and don't have any dependency between ... but in principle, if you would trace it down to single instruction, it's still being processed and executed in a way very similar to the description above)

Comment: According to my textbook Computer Architecture Design by Morris Mano , it is a micro-operation which is happening in 1 cycle time assuming that memory access takes less than 1 cycle time. So how are memory cell enabled by the AR and valued being copied to AR occurring at the same transition?

Comment: I guess the memory chip is connected to CPU through data bus, i.e. address lines + data lines + control lines. So you set up address lines at the beginning (it's basically copy of AR, not AR itself), and toward end of the cycle you copy data lines into AR ... but I don't believe this can be single cycle "ad hoc" without actually designing these steps being non-colliding. I'm not sure what's going on in your book. If they are oversimplifying because the focus is on different aspects of Computer Architecture in that part of book, or opposite, their complex architecture being capable of this.

Comment: But without seeing the book, I would guess their single cycle would be split into micro-steps in real world implementation, dealing with the operation in a way similar to the description in my answer. I can't even imagine any principally different approach, although there's lot of subtlety to it, in the real world, like systems using both raising/falling edge of clock signal to do actually two sub-steps per single tick, etc... (I'm not HW guy, quite opposite, my expertise starts when you can say about signal it's "0" or "1", as long as it's electricity, I'm kinda complete noob)

Comment: @AmishaBansal and Ped7g: old non-pipelined CPUs do often use the clock for internal steps, and different instructions take different numbers of steps.  (Unless you pad the fast instructions with do-nothing cycles).  e.g. Z80 T-states [Z80 and video chip contending for random access](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4846) - apparently T-states are bus cycles, and each M-state (machine cycle) is at least 3 T-states long.  But it's variable with some instructions taking more T-states per M-state.

Comment: It is also written,”An edge-triggered methodology allows a state element to be read and written in the same clock cycle without creating a race that could lead to indeterminate data values.” Does this mean due to the fact that we are using edge triggered registers we can read and load in same cycle?

Comment: @AmishaBansal for me (non HW guy caring only about "algorithm" level) it reads as: "the read and write happens in different discrete times = no race". Whether they use faster clock and step per single clock signal (as in my answer), or whether they step by falling/raising edge of single clock signal (i.e. two (or even more?) steps per single clock) is for me the same thing, just giving single step different time unit (single clock tick vs single. edge trigger). Of course it may be vastly different how you implement it on the HW side, then the difference probably matters. But not in logic.

Comment: @AmishaBansal anyway, I think the main point I was trying to show you was, that the electricity current needs time to establish it's path through the circuitry, i.e. if you would watch the signals in the CPU on the gates with some super time zoom, you would see the output of logical circuits to be very often in some fluctuating undefined state flipping from state to state or even hovering in middle, and taking considerable amount of some time unit before it stabilizes into final answer, and that's the reason why CPU use those crystals with frequencies, to split the time into discrete steps.

Comment: how your particular CPU from the book does implement this into detail, is beyond my knowledge :/ (didn't read that book), so I can't help you more with that, but I would expect the book either explain itself reasonably, or ask somebody doing HW logic circuits design, I'm pretty sure this trade has whole years of knowledge of details I am not aware of, which may make this naive entry-level overview kinda funny (although I believe my info would hold, i.e. it's not "wrong", just missing ton of detail and subtlety)